# Go to the last clicked element on mouseleave

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

What I am trying to accomplish is:

1. **mouseenter**: after **hovering** 1 of 5 boxes the background of a section changes, depending on which one of these 5 is hovered.
2. **click**: after **clicking** on one of the 5 boxes, the background of the section below stops on the respective image, depending on the clicked box.
3. **mouseleave**: after this event the background of the section should go back to the last clicked one or the default selected if no clicks.

Here's a pen I did, it would be easier to understand what I want to accomplish: https://codepen.io/karamanliev/pen/YewOpG

```
$box = jQuery(".box");
$boxes = jQuery(".boxes");
$section = jQuery(".section-bg");
$default = jQuery(".--3");

jQuery($box).mouseenter(function() {

    $section.eq(jQuery(this).index()).siblings().removeClass("active");
    $section.eq(jQuery(this).index()).addClass("active");

    jQuery($box).click(function() {

        $section.eq(jQuery(this).index()).siblings().removeClass("active");
        $section.eq(jQuery(this).index()).addClass("active");

        jQuery(this).attr('clicked', 'yes'); 
        return true;

    });
}).mouseleave(function() {

    if (jQuery(this).attr('clicked') != 'yes') {
        $section.eq(jQuery(this).index()).removeClass("active");
        $default.addClass("active");

    }

});
```

The problem is after I've already clicked a box and hover again, it will go back to the selected by default (--3).

Comment: I try to replicate the issue that you're having in your codepen and I can't

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1st:** You need to add `clicked="yes"` to the active box

```
<div class="box active" clicked="yes">
  <p>3</p>
</div>
```

**2nd** You need to remove the `clicked` attribute from unactive boxes

```
 jQuery($box).removeAttr('clicked');
```

**3rd** no need to use `$default` or use `if` statement to check for `clicked` attribute on `mouseleave()`.. its enough to use `.filter()`

```
$section.removeClass('active');
$section.eq(jQuery($box).filter('.active[clicked]').index()).addClass("active");
```

[**CodePen**](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/RQreRy)

Comment: I've deleted my old comment as I managed to get it working, but for some reason, on the first hovers (without clicking) when I mouseleave the active goes to my last $box, not to the default one I've set in the html.

Comment: Sure I did. I see it's working there and I really can't understand why it doesn't work for me. It's for a wordpress site I'm building, but the structure and the logic are the same.

Comment: For some reason removing the whole [clicked] check is working for me. I'm kind of confused: https://codepen.io/karamanliev/pen/MQKdYg

Comment: @MindPhuq it was a good job to work without `[clicked]` you done well .. why you're confusing??